# Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <ViewController> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I´m new to Xcode but I keep on making some small apps to learn. I have run into a problem that only sometimes occurs with the message "Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!" and the app then crash.

I have searched around and found some possible answers but no luck for me yet.

My code for back is:

```
- (IBAction)Back {
UIViewController *back = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:back animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

I understand that the problem is that I try to go from one viewcontroller to another before the presentation of the viewcontroller is done.

The strangest thing is that this sometimes isn´t any problem and the app works flawlessly.

Comment: Right now, your code doesn't really make much sense... Why are you presenting one view controller then immediately attempting to dismiss the root view?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have noticed the same when reading the code now, so I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you have trouble with the concept of navigation in iOS. First take a look at [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Navigation.html), and then read: [Navigate with UINavigationController in iOS7](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/navigate-with-uinavigationcontroller-in-ios7) (don't worry about ios 7 or 8, they're both similar)

Overall, I really recommend watching Stanford's [Developing iOS 7 apps for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) or following the newest one: [Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099) to learn!

Comment: upvote to undo the down vote. Armin is just trying to be helpful.